# AWS SQS - How to process one message at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I have a FIFO Queue in the AWS SQS, which is trigger's Lambda function.
I want to process each messages in Lambda function without parallel execution (one message at a time)

For example: If I have a message A, B, C in the queue. My lambda should complete A, then start B etc.,

My current config of the FIFO queue is

```
Message retention period: 4 Days
Default visibility timeout: 1 Hour 30 Minutes
Delivery delay: 0 sec
Receive message wait time: 0 Second
```

Comment: Just make sure the lambda only has a batch size of 1 configured. Do all messages have the same message group id? If not: additionally limit the concurrency of your lambda to 1.

Comment: @luk2302 I fixed it with same message group ID and unique deduplication ID. Thanks for your support. Add your solution to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

set up another lamba(add/setup trigger to invoke this lamba for every one minute using Amazon event brige rule).
In the lamba funtion using receivemessage api call( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) you can fetch desired number of messages from sqs queue (max 10 messages) and delete after processing each message.